# Программа вылетает по таймауту. Python Stem

Tags: python, requests, tor

Пишу программу подключения к сети Tor для анонимного парсинга, но ничего не выходит, смотрел разные статьи, использовал разные библиотеки (torpy,torrequests), пробовал все это на линуксе и винде - бузуспешно! Одна и таже проблема - Программа завершается по таймауту. Сейчас использую библиотеку **Stem**
 Вот код из примеров:

```
import requests
from stem.process import launch_tor
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller


def newIP():
    with Controller.from_port(port = 9151) as controller:
        controller.authenticate()
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        print("\n\nNEW IP, NEW IP\n\n")

def print_status(line):
    if("100" in line):
        print(line)

tor_cmd = "tor"

data = requests.get("https://api.myip.com/")
print("before Tor:", data.json())

tor = launch_tor(tor_cmd=tor_cmd, init_msg_handler= print_status, 
    take_ownership=True)
print("Tor launched!")
for i in range(5):
    try:
        with requests.Session() as sess:
            sess.proxies = {'http' : 'SOCKS5://127.0.0.1:9050', 'https': 'SOCKS5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
        data = sess.get('https://api.myip.com/', timeout=10)
        print("After Tor:", data.json())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        newIP()

tor.terminate()
```

На винде просто зависает потому что нелльзя timeout использовать
на линуксе выдает - **OSError: reached a 10 second timeout without success**
Сам Tor установлен путь добавлен в PATH. В torrc, конкретно в этом примере ничего не изменял.

Comment: У вас что-то с отступами в контекстном менеджере сессии. Но проблема, наверное, вообще в другом.